# Android Studio：cannot resolve some symbols when open AOSP

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I am struggling with  android source code in Android studio. I am confused by some problems which mainly are "cannot resolve symbol xxx", see the picture below:
[image]

While when I open the symbol class(eg:RemoteAnimationTarget),it seems fine:
[image]

why it happened like this?

Besides, more settings about my project are attached below:
[image]

please give me some ideas.

Comment: gradle sync and then rebuild the project. It should start working.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal note that this is AOSP, not an app.

Comment: Did you run aidegen? AOSP code cannot directly be opened in Android Studio right now. Also check the ASfP https://developer.android.com/studio/platform